# C, does an array require more memory space than just its elements?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

Say we have a char array of size 40,

```
char buffer[40];
```

Secondly, let's say that this array is completely full, that someone has written 40 characters to it.

Thus, we could say that the elements of this array take up 40 bytes, as each char is 1 byte.

My question is this:
How much space does our array ***actually*** take up in memory? Will it take up 40 bytes of space, or more? Are extra bits needed to identify this array as of type char, and are extra bits needed to allow for null termination? If so, it could be that we need something more like ~42 bytes to store this array in memory.

As such, I want to know if I can reliably fit an array of 40 chars in a memory space with 40 allocated bytes.

Comment: What did you try? A debugger will show this very easily. Or print the size of the array. Where is your code? What does your C book say? And why would y completely statically typed language like C have to track the type at run-time?

Comment: Generally all the type checking and details of how to access different types are worked out at compile time, and no extra data needs to be stored with the variable at run time.

Comment: You can reliably fit 40 bytes into a 40 byte array. What you can't do is fit a 40-character nul-terminated string into a 40 byte array. It would have to be 39 characters plus the `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I really appreciate it and found all your comments helpful. I was just asking the question in general, as I'm planning out a shadow file system and want to avoid seg faults (memory novice here).

Comment: Gotcha David, thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike languages like Java or C#, C does not store any type meta information at runtime. Therefore, `char[40]` requires exactly 40 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It takes up exactly `sizeof buffer` (a constant) bytes.
As `buffer` is an array of 40 `char` that is the same as `40 * sizeof (char)` which is 40 (`sizeof (char)` by definition is 1).

The eventual space for the terminating zero byte for strings must be one of those 40. It's the programmer's responsibility to account for that byte.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly it will take 40bytes, There is no need to check type. Ultimately we are storing the binary value of ASCII value of char from array.
And its up to you how will you print this value, in int or char.
Second point about termination, so compiler will not put any termination, bcoz size of array is predefined. Compiler will print or fetch array value from 0 to defined size.
This is my understanding,
Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not true. (I'm thinking "struct[]" here.) But, you've asked specifically about `char[]` so it is.

(Also, there could be overhead/padding on the stack or heap, but that's not part of the declared data structure.)

As for `char[]` having something to do with characters and null-terminated strings (which, of course, it *sometimes* does), the only case where more memory is allocated than you might expect is in a string literal: `"8 chars"`is equivalent to `{ '8', ' ', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 's', '\0' }`. (This makes a few assumptions about the source character set and execution character set that the compiler is told to use, but you get the idea. [It could be `"₹"` is equivalent to `{ 0xE2, 0x82, 0xB9, 0x00 }`])